# Asp.net Converting into "MMM/yyyy" issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

Converting the template field value.

The default is shown like `01-03-2015 00:00:00`

I need in `MMM/yyyy` format

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MonthYear" SortExpression="MonthYear">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MonthYear")%>'></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832691/asp-net-formatting-datetime-in-gridview

Comment: You mean someting like `Apr 2015` format?

Comment: Does this work? `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("MonthYear")).ToString("MMM yyyy")%>'></asp:TextBox>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("MonthYear")).ToString("MMM yyyy")%>'></asp:TextBox>
```