# Date format in tag

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview

I have an `<a>` tag as per the following:

```
 <a href="#" title="data">cerca </a>
```

which holds a date. It is part of an ASP.NET GridView:

```
<asp:TemplateField> 
  <HeaderTemplate> 
    Data Inizio &nbsp; <a href="#" title="data">cerca </a> 
  </HeaderTemplate> 
  <ItemTemplate> <%# Eval("iniziodata") %> </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField> 
<asp:BoundField DataField="inizioora" HeaderText="Ora Inizio" SortExpression="inizioora"></asp:BoundField> 
<asp:BoundField DataField="finedata" HeaderText="Data Fine" SortExpression="finedata" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
```

I want to format it in dd/MM/yyyy format. How can I do that?

Comment: What did you try ? Can we see ?

Comment: How are you creating this tag? Is it created using some code you wrote?

Comment: It is part of a gridview

Comment: <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
                      Data Inizio &nbsp;
           <a href="#" title="data">cerca </a>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("iniziodata") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:BoundField DataField="inizioora" HeaderText="Ora Inizio" SortExpression="inizioora"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="finedata" HeaderText="Data Fine" SortExpression="finedata" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>

Comment: I tried with inserting DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" but it doesn't work

Comment: Right now you seem to have a static string "cerca" inside your `<a>` tag. Where are you adding the date into it?

Comment: Cerca is in the header. The date in <ItemTemplate> <%# Eval("iniziodata") %> </ItemTemplate>

Comment: Why did you ask about changing `<a href="#" title="data">cerca </a>` then?? Makes no sense.

Comment: Anyway see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832691/asp-net-formatting-datetime-in-gridview (and also https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+gridview+eval+date+format&oq=asp.net+gridview+eval+da&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.4879j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 for more similar resources). Did you not search for this at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try in Bound Field

```
DataFormatString="{0:d}"
```

or in TemplateField

```
<a href="#" title="data"><%# Bind("Date", "{0:d}")%></a>
```