# Inline C# code vs Page_Load method

Tags: c#, asp.net, inline, code-behind, pageload

I am working on an ASP.NET Web Application.
I have two files -> example.aspx and its code behind example.aspx.cs

I am wondering what the difference is between putting inline C# code at the top of example.aspx

```
<%    
    if (Session["Page"] != null)
    {    
        //method that maps session vars to form elements
        loadSessionData();
    }        
%>
```

and putting the code in the Page_Load() method of the code behind file example.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (Session["Page"] != null)
     {    
         //method that maps session vars to form elements
         loadSessionData();
     }  
}
```

Depending where I put the code the application behaves different in regards to loading the session data into the form elements.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
I figured out why depending on where I put the code the application behaved differently.  If I put the inline C# method call at the top of the .aspx it does not run on postbacks.  If I put the C# method call in the Page_Load() method of the .aspx.cs code behind file it does run on postbacks.  So if I want to put the method in the Page_Load method but not run it on postbacks I would need to wrap it in:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    loadSessionData();
}
```

Comment: The `<%...%>` is run as the page renders....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think the biggest difference would be the moment when the code is executed. Page_Load occurres before the Page_Render which is when (I think) inline code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

if you are just asking Inline Coding VS code behind , this is worth checking.
[ASP.NET - Inline vs. Code-Behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201418/asp-net-inline-vs-code-behind)