# How can I make common footer for my repeaters?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, repeater

I Assume this question may be appear very dumb for ones.. But I have multiple repeaters in my asp application I wonder how I can make some things common like footer..

And How can I create events for my repeater? Like a button in the footer who raise an Custom event? Thanks for responses..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `UserControl` and put that in your footers.

For events you need to hook your footer up to the `ItemCommand handler`.

```
<asp:repeater runat='server' id='myRepeater' onItemCommand='rptMyRepeater_ItemCommand'>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <!-- markup and controls -->
    </ItemTemplate>
    <footerTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat='server' id='btnOrf' Text='Click Me' CommandName='SomeAction' CommandArgument='100' />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Then in your codebehind you define a method which handles the repeater's `ItemCommand` event. You'll need to check the `ItemCommandEventArgs` parameter for details of the button/control that raised the event:

```
protected void rptMyRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e){
    if (e.CommandName == "SomeAction"){
        Response.Write ("The Command was " + e.CommandName + " and the value of the CommandArgument is: " + e.CommandArgument);

    }
}
```

You can have as many buttons as you like and with different `Commandname`s and `CommandArgument`s e.g. 'Add', 'Save', 'Delete', 'Update' etc.

Usually you bind something like the database `ID` of the dataitem (Users/Products/whatever) to the CommandArgument so you know how to identify the object being edited/saved/deleted/whatever.

```
<asp:Button runat='server' id='saveBtn' commandName='delete' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserId")%>' Text='Save' />
```

Full Example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178093.aspx) should always be your first point of reference ;-)

Comment: @5arx Thanks a lot!! but I don't see how I can specify the content of ItemTemplate markUp because once he is Specified he can be modified separatly?

Comment: @Orf - not sure what you mean? The markup of the ItemTemplate is just markup i.e. HTML + ASP.Net controls. You can change it to whatever you like whenever you like.

Comment: `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserId")%>'` <-- I WISH people would NOT promote this style of coding, it's spaghetti coding and it's bad.

Comment: In fact I want only the footer template common with all repeater and items totally free.

Comment: Actually, its a matter of opinion. LOTS of markup can get messy, but at the same time declarative code like this is as valid as imperative - check the MSDN documentation. I personally wouldn't have markup full of this style, but similarly, some people don't like lots of C# code to wire up their Controls.

Comment: If we look at the MSDN documentation then it recommends NOT using eval since it uses reflection. People who don't want to write C# to write up their controls are lazy. Separating the two is far more maintainable, specifically if you want someone to sit write HTML.

Comment: @Orf - I'm trying to understand - do you want to put the button in a common control inside the repeater? Not a button inside the repeater? So the button is part of the common control ?

Comment: Why not but I just think it is possible to have a "custom repeater". With this repeater I only have to specify ItemTemplate. Footer template is already written somewhere else and contain the button.
But maybe it is not possible.

Comment: @Phill - as I suggested earlier, I personally wouldn't use this style in production code.  

However given the current state of the OP's knowledge and understanding of .Net, using the declarative style is probably wise when explaining the basics - an example involving codebehind would be unnecessarily complicated. First code it right, then make it pretty, fast etc. ;-)

Comment: Sure Orf, you can implement your own and re-use it.

Comment: @Orf - you can do it this way - see here for a simple example of the sort of thing that would be involved : http://programming.top54u.com/post/ASP-Net-Repeater-dynamically-using-C-sharp-code.aspx.

Personally I prefer to use the 'common usercontrol' approach - writing Repeaters as per the article above is fairly close to writing Custom Controls i.e. gets complicated because you're manually adding/outputting HTML.

Comment: @Phill but how? How can I do that?

Comment: @Phill - "People who don't want to write C# to write up their controls are lazy." Ha ha ha are you serious ...?

Comment: @5arx - you only just noticed that comment? Yes it is lazy, binding in your markup is bad practice. This isn't classic ASP.

Comment: @Phill - no I noticed it yesterday but I forgot to respond as I was busy chuckling at your arrogance. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702343/ondatabinding-vs-inline-pros-cons-and-overhead  - its mostly about style choice.

And then there's MVC to consider ...  a little humility goes a long way ;-)

Comment: There are major differences to the code used in MVC and code used in Web Forms. But MVC suffers from two major flaws itself, one of which is people who write helper methods in their view, or use their domain models as view-models.

Comment: So now as well as calling the vast majority of ASP.Net coders 'lazy' you're picking holes in the ASP.Net MVC framework as well? 

All righty then - I think its best I leave you to it. Perhaps you could take this up with members of the Microsoft MVC project teams ...? Your arguments are likely to go waay over MY head ;-)

Comment: Now you're just making yourself look like an idiot, they are not technical flaws in the framework, talking to the MVC project team can't change HOW people use the framework, they are flaws in the way the framework is used. You can't stop people from being stupid enough to write helper methods directly in the view, or use the domain model as a view model. If you want to continue turning the .NET community into a bunch of lazy developers by advocating spaghetti coding, putting code in the wrong places, and incorrectly using frameworks, go for it, it's not like I can stop you.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't share your evangelistic zeal for moulding the .NET community in my image - I'm just trying to answer a newbie's question in a simple way so he can get on with learning to be as much of a genius coder as you apparently think yourself to be.

If you look at any basic primer on .Net and databinding you'll see that I'm not alone in using  inline databinding expressions to illustrate fundamental concepts. Take up your argument with Scott Guthrie & Co. I'm too busy coding to support my family to argue with you ;-)

Peace.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you need to create a TABLE
   structure with help of header,
   ItemTemplate, and footer templates

   ```
   <HeaderTemplate>
       <table>
           <Tr>
               <Td>Header</Td>
           </Tr>
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <Tr>
           <Td>Header</Td>
       </Tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
           <Tr>
               <Td>Header</Td>
           </Tr>
       </Table>
   </FooterTemplate>
   ```
2. You need to find control in footer and assign events. Like this:

   ```
   void Repeater_OnItemDataBound(object source, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
       {
           Button SelectAll = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("SelectAll");
       }
   }
   ```